# unable to make xpath <button ===class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" ng-click="SignUp();" type="submit">Sign in</button>

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

Hi I am unable make xpath and want to click on sign in button .

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" ng-click="SignUp();" type="submit">Sign in</button>
```

I am using `//a[@text = 'Sign in']`

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" ng-click="SignUp();" type="submit">Sign in</button>
```

Comment: You need to spend some time reading some basic XPath tutorials, blogs, and other questions on SO. Your XPath shows a lack of basic understanding and questions like this have been asked and answered many times here.

Comment: please send some link , references so that I am able to make basics xpath

Answer (score 0):

The `sign in` button is in `<button>` tag, not `<a>` tag, and there isn't `text` attribute, only a `text()` method. Use

```
//button[contains(text(), 'Sign in')]
```

Comment: <a class="btn btn-primary" style=" width:200px" href="patient_enrollment.php"> Patient Enrollment </a> and I use driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text() = 'Patient Enrollment']")).click(); but not working

Comment: @user1904103 If you have a new question you should post a new question with all the relevant data (error, html etc).